# Mimic Excel copy/paste in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I am trying to mimic Excel's copy/paste within Tabulator.  Simply put, I want to copy (ctrl+c) a couple of cell values and then paste them somewhere else in the table.

My idea is to:

1. copy a couple of cells
2. click on the cell where I want to start pasting from.
3. Store that cell's object somewhere so I can reference it when I paste the data
4. Ctrl+v or right click paste
5. Using the clicked cell I have stored as well as [clipboardPasteParser callback](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/clipboard#paste-parser), I would like to build a rowData object to return from that callback (as described in the docs).
6. Using the [clipboardPasteAction callback](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/clipboard#paste-action), I will take that rowData object and use it to update the cells.

However, as far as I understand, Tabulator's clipboard functionality does not facilitate this kind of copy/paste action. In the below code snippet you will see that I console.log out the result of paste in the `clipboardPasteParser(clipboard)` callback. `clipboard` is just a concatenated string of the copied values.

For example, copying "Mary May", "1", "female", "2", and "blue", results in the string "Mary May1female2blue" in the `clipboard` callback variable.

[image]

Here is the code if you would like to try it out.

```js
var data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Mrs. Rafaela Barton',
    progress: 50,
    gender: 'male',
    height: 4,
    col: 'GhostWhite',
    dob: '02/10/1986',
    driver: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Grant Kunze',
    progress: 16,
    gender: 'female',
    height: 4,
    col: 'DarkViolet',
    dob: '05/07/1993',
    driver: true
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Marilou Morar',
    progress: 30,
    gender: 'female',
    height: 2,
    col: 'Turquoise',
    dob: '14/10/1984',
    driver: true
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: 'Nathan Fadel Jr.',
    progress: 78,
    gender: 'female',
    height: 4,
    col: 'SkyBlue',
    dob: '01/11/1921',
    driver: false
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Mrs. Amya Eichmann',
    progress: 44,
    gender: 'female',
    height: 3,
    col: 'Aquamarine',
    dob: '20/02/1937',
    driver: false
  }
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height:"311px",
    data: data,
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name", width:150},
        {title:"Height", field:"height", bottomCalc:"sum"},
        {title:"Progress", field:"progress", formatter:"progress", sorter:"number"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Rating", field:"rating", formatter:"star", hozAlign:"center", width:100},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", hozAlign:"center", sorter:"date"},
        {title:"Driver", field:"car", hozAlign:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
    ],
    clipboard:true,
    clipboardPasteParser: function(clipboard) {
        console.log(clipboard);
    },
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example-table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way that I can get the callback parameter to somehow separate the values so I can parse it in the clipboardPasteParser callback? Is that possible?  Am I perhaps missing something?

I have sneaking suspicion that this problem has less to do with Tabulator and more about how the browser handles copy.  It would still be a nice feature if Tabulator was able to handle this natively.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but cell selection will be coming in the 5.0 release in a couple of months

Comment: Hi Oli, Can you please confirm if this is going to part of 5.0 release? It seems that's not the case by looking at the example here: http://tabulator.info/examples/5.0?#clipboard Thanks